# How to set bitrate with webRTC in js？

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Here is the code

```
var constraints = {
       video: {
          width: {exact: 320},
          height: {exact: 240},
          bitRate: {
            max: 400,
            min: 400,
          },
          frameRate: {
            min: 15,
            max: 15
          }
        },
      }

window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

It seems width, height, frameRate all work fine, but bitRate not works.

Can js set bitRate in webRTC, or any other way reduce record video size？

I test find that video size record in iPhone safari too big to wait uploading.

Comment: Your server should have adequate bitrate estimation and WebRTC will follow suit without you needing to plug any of this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MediaStream` that you get when calling `getUserMedia()` doesn't know anything about bitrates. It's always dealing with the raw media.

But you can control the bitrate when sending the `MediaStream` via a `PeerConnection`. It can be either done by manually modifying the SDP or by updating the parameters of the corresponding sender.

```
const senders = peerConnection.getSenders();

// Let's say you want to modify the first.
const parameters = senders[0].getParameters();

parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = YOUR_MAX_BITRATE;

sender.setParameters(parameters);
```

You can also set the bitrate when recording the `MediaStream` with a `MediaRecorder`.

```
new MediaRecorder(
    mediaStream,
    {
        // You can either set the values for audio and video separately ...
        audioBitsPerSecond: YOUR_MAX_BITRATE_FOR_AUDIO,
        videoBitsPerSecond: YOUR_MAX_BITRATE_FOR_VIDEO,
        // ... or you define one value for audio and video.
        bitsPerSecond: YOUR_MAX_BITRATE_FOR_AUDIO_AND_VIDEO
    }
);
```